# How to : Working with MVVM Dialog by FantasticFiasco need help injecting IDialogService with Caliburn.Micro

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I need help in using MVVM Dialog (https://github.com/FantasticFiasco/mvvm-dialogs).
I want to use this library in my existing app but I dont know how to inject this IDialogService from bootsrapper.

Following is the Link for reference how they are passing IDialogService :

https://github.com/FantasticFiasco/mvvm-dialogs/blob/master/samples/net-framework/Demo.SaveFileDialog/App.xaml.cs

Following is the Link of a sample Dialog demonstrating usage of IDialogService :

https://github.com/FantasticFiasco/mvvm-dialogs/blob/master/samples/net-framework/Demo.SaveFileDialog/MainWindowViewModel.cs

Maybe this is very basic request but I am not sure how to inject this service with Caliburn.Micro, and MVVM Dialog library is using MVVMLight for which I am not aware of.

Thank you and sorry for this silly question.

Comment: Is there a bootstrapper included in Caliburn? I think so. I think you should inherit from that bootstrapper and bind your IDialogService in one of the overrideable methods. I don't know the details. Can you show some code what you are trying?

Comment: are you aware of this docu page: https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/bootstrapper ?

Comment: If nobody else gets there before me, I can help you tonight or at latest tomorrow. But it would be helpful if you could provide me with a very basic sample on GitHub, it would make sure that I’m solving the correct problem.

Comment: @FantasticFiasco thank you for response, I've added this https://github.com/infirazor/TabsDemo it is having basic caliburn micro configuration.

Comment: @SvenBardos I am checking on it further. But just a help would be great..thanks

Comment: I've created a PR on you repo, this works well for message boxes and open/save file dialogs, but I have to investigate further when it comes to opening your own windows/dialogs. My plan is to provide a demo app showing integration with Caliburn.Micro, but I will post that as an answer when its done. Don't hesitate to also post these kind of questions on the GitHub repo. There's a chance I could have missed this question, and it's a good one.

Comment: @FantasticFiasco thank you so much for this much response buddy ! yes i checked and it works fine upto open/save file dialogs. Lets see how it works wit Custom Model Dialog. Now the best part if you will make a demo with Caliburm.Micro, thats next level thing that will help lot of developers.

Answer (score 0):

The [GitHub repository for MVVM Dialogs](https://github.com/FantasticFiasco/mvvm-dialogs) now has a section in its `README.md` with links to integrations into other MVVM frameworks, where Caliburn.Micro is among them.